# What's the maximal frequency of WMI queries?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, wmi

As explained in [this previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1422789/whats-the-link-between-a-wmi-using-application-and-the-wmiprvse-exe-process), I'm dealing with some serious `WMI` issues. Now one of the options I'd like to explore is the maximal frequency of `WMI` queries, if any:

Imagine a `WMIPrvSE.exe` process goes down, due to a quota overflow, is there a minimum time I need to wait before launching a new `WMI` request, or is a new `WMIPrvSE.exe` process started up, in order to handle my new request?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT: sorry for the late reply, but we can't increase WMI quota anymore: this has already been done in the past and I'm afraid this would just cause the quota overflow to appear less frequently, while we are looking for a way to avoid them completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some result of my tests, where I dropped some of the three instances of
`WmiPrvSE.exe` that I could see running under the credentials of SYSTEM,
LOCAL SERVICE and NETWORK SERVICE.

Dropping the instances manually one by one in Task Manager,
two of them were immediately restarted in a matter of seconds.
The LOCAL SERVICE instance was not restarted,
and to have it running again took a restart of the system service
"Windows Management Instrumentation".

I don't rightly know if the LOCAL SERVICE instance will not be restarted
immediately when needed, but if you wish to restart the
"Windows Management Instrumentation" service, the only method I found was
to run in an elevated Command Prompt (cmd):

```
powershell -command "Restart-Service Winmgmt -Force"
```

This command only took a few seconds to complete.
All other restart methods using the `net` and `sc` commands were not effective
on this service.

If restarting the service re-initializes the used quota,
you might schedule the above command to run every few hours/days as required.

Comment: I'm sorry, the customer did not respond yet to this proposal. As you are the only person who has given a real answer and the bounty expires tomorrow, I've decided to grant you the bounty.